# div relative to change Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a payment page that build from main page and third party iframe. 
Under the iframe there is a relative div. 
My problem is that sometimes the iframe add some warnning messegase at the bottom of it and override the relative div. see links for screen shots: [pic1](https://www.visa-usa.co.il/1.JPG) and [pic2](https://www.visa-usa.co.il/2.JPG)

what should I do in order to make my div position will adjusted to the Iframe?

Comment: Is the warning programed by yourself?

Comment: no, I receive it from the third party....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it just by leaving enough space between the iframe and the button, so if the warning messages appears, the button is very close to the messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t do this, as the iframe is from another source. So it´s not possible to look at it´s contents, due to cross-domain poilicies.. Your only option is to make the iframe smaller (so a scrollbar gets displayed) or move your "hint" further down.

I guess it´s illegal anyway to modify a payment processors site, by overlaying other content, that suggest, it is part of the payment processors process!